# how to convert a streaming dataset into JavaRDD in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, dataset, rdd, spark-structured-streaming

I have a structured streaming application that reads from a hdfs path.

```
structStream = spark.readStream().format("text").load(parameters.get("input"));

JavaRDD<String> transformedstructStreamRDD = structStream.as(Encoders.STRING()).toJavaRDD();

Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(transformedstructStreamRDD, String.class);
//Dataset<Row> df = structStream.as("dummy");

StreamingQuery streamingQuery = df.writeStream().format("csv").option("checkpointLocation","/user/hadoop/chkpointpath/").option("path", "/user/hadoop/output/").start();
try {
        streamingQuery.awaitTermination();
    } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the above code is failing at the point where RDD conversion takes place. If i comment out the 2nd and 3rd line of code, and uncomment the 4th line, the streamin application gets started. But I want the RDD conversion to happen so I can do further transformations on RDD. Any help is appreciated. TIA. The exception im facing is :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
```